# Visual Studio Online (hosted build controller) and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I keep having issues with the combination TypeScript and the Hosted Build Controller of Visual Studio Online.

Locally, when we build our solution I see the TypeScript errors (after enforcing an error in the ts file, to trigger compilation). The build succeeds, but we see the errors.

In our CI build, where we set our sln as project to build, we don't have the errors.
But our build config where we deploy (publish profile, webdeploy) to our website, we do have the errors, like our local build, and now the build fails. And we don't have that many TypeScript errors reported as our local build.
(project to build is now the web csproj and the msbuild arguments, /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="###.pubxml" /p:Password=### /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0)

Doing a publish (webdeploy) locally works again, no failed build.

What do I miss to have a consistent behavior? Between our local env, CI and deploy build configs. Situation locally is ok, we see the errors, but not blocking. But I would like to see that our CI build has the same behavior as the deploy build. And see the same TypeScript errors locally and on build server.

Or have I the wrong approach.

FYI: I have TypeScript 0.9.1.1 installed, like the build controller (http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/hosted-build-controller-vs.aspx - Software on the hosted build server)

Many thanks

EDIT:
a combination of 2 changes fixed some my problems. I use TypeScript 1.0 now, released yesterday, and I commit this version into source control, to use on the hosted build controller. (http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/09/typescript-on-your-build-server.html)

The errors locally and on the build server are now the same.

The only thing that I still would like to see resolved, is that our CI build also compiles the ts files, without doing a deploy.